# With Powerapps, how can I make a field conditionally mandatory?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, syntax

I'm trying to make fields conditionally mandatory for example, if Status field = "Red", make the Comments field required.

I can see where I can put a formula in the 'required' section of the Comments field but I can't get a valid formula in there.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing a similar thing based on the input on a drop down menu, you could refactor this for your purposes.

```
If("Some Text" in DataCardValue2.Selected.Value,true,false)
```

The above will return true if the condition is met, and false if not. Resulting in a conditionally required field.

So if you wanted to ensure a field was not empty for example, you could do something like:

```
If(DataCardValue3.Text = "",true,false)
```

This will return required true if there is no text in the field.

You can also base this stuff on various style properties, here's an example of checking if the field has a red border:

```
If(TextInput1.BorderColor = RGBA(255,0,0,1),true,false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you are on the right path. Use the "Required" property of the datacard and type in this:

Assuming DataCardValue7 is your status field-
If(DataCardValue7.Value="Red",true,false)

Comment: **Required : If("Some Text" in DataCardValue2.Selected.Value,true,false)** Thank you so much for sharing your valuable input. It literally saved me. It works amazingly.